# Handling fragment transaction in android.

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I am developing android application in which I am using one activity and two fragments. Consider same example which google explain like one list view and detail view. on click of list item we are rendering respective detail fragment.

So I learn how to do fragment transaction and i come up with two solutions. One which is standard way which google explain that make one interface and implement that interface into main activity. And do fragment transaction there inside main activity.

I tried with another way. when I click on list item inside click listener instead of calling interface I change fragment inside my list fragment only and its working fine.

So i want to know what is difference between those to methods. changing fragment from main activity and changing it from fragment only.

What kind of problem i will face if i implement with second method.i.e. changing from fragment only.

Need Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What kind of problem i will face if i implement with second
>   method.i.e. changing from fragment only.

There isn't an actual problem, it's more of a design discussion. Using the second approach means you're making a very specific fragment, one that on a click on one of its rows will make a transaction with a specific fragment on a specific place of the holder activity. This would be a problem if you plan on reusing this fragment.

Suppose you have this `ListFragment` and you decided that it should be used in five other activities(with different data). Because it has a very precise action when clicking one of its rows, this fragment will always require the holder activity to have a specific container(where the transaction will be done) along the specific detail fragment with which it was initially used. The problem is that in each of those five activities you may want to use a different fragment when clicking a row of the `ListFragment`, this would require making changes to the class of the `ListFragment`.

Now suppose you have the same behavior with the interface approach. As the `ListFragment` doesn't know or care who handles that click event(as it passes it to whoever registers as the listener) you can simply put the `ListFragment` in the five activities with no problem(so no changes to it at all). In the interface method of the activity you could then implement the desired behavior with whatever fragment you want and in whatever container setup you want.